# How can I make my animate.css animation loop forever?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animate.css

How can I make my animate.css animation last forever? I tried to use `animationIterationCount = "infinite"`. However, this doesn't seem to have worked.

This is the plugin I'm using. `import { Flash } from 'animate-css-styled-components';`

```
 <Flash duration=".8s" delay="1s" animationIterationCount = "infinite">
 <Button primary>LOG IN <AiFillLock /></Button>
 </Flash>
```

Thank you!

Comment: use iterationCount="infinite" instead of  animationIterationCount="infinite". Documentation says so. Check the props it accept here. https://github.com/dielduarte/animate-css-styled-components#props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd need to use `iterationCount` as the prop.

```
<Flash duration=".8s" delay="1s" iterationCount="infinite" >
 <Button primary>LOG IN <AiFillLock /></Button>
</Flash>
```

And ensure you have styled-component installed.

Answer (score 0):

This `animation-iteration-count` property is used in CSS, if you want to write it in a form of JSX there is `iterationCount` prop. You can use this prop and set it to `infinite`.

So for your case:

```
<Flash duration=".8s" delay="1s" iterationCount="infinite">
  <Button primary>LOG IN <AiFillLock /></Button>
</Flash>
```

Comment: Thank you, I would've marked it as the right answer but Capt wrote it first. Thank you!